Assignment problem for multiple time instants
I need to assign a fixed set of technicians to a different set of customers S_t at every time instant t. There are location coordinates corresponding to each customer. The mapping of technician to customer would be one to one. The objective would be minimise total distance traveled by technicians while maximising customers serviced.
One could apply the Hungarian algorithm for the assignment problem at each time instant. But how to show whether this indeed gives global min ?
Are there any other approaches to consider?
Thanks!
